# SQL Profiler not displaying all ADO.NET operations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-profiler

I have the following code which creates a serializable transaction. The application works as expected:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0) }))
{
  // Modify database using EF.
  tx.Complete();
}
```

However, profiling the database is causing me some confusion.

```
// Start of transaction (and the first query). Login has invalid ISO LEV.
Audit Login       ... set transaction isolation level read committed ...
SQLTransaction    0 - Begin
RPC:Completed     exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1)... 

// Second query in transaction. Login now has valid ISO LEV.
Audit Logout
RPC:Completed     exec sp_reset_connection
Audit Login       ... set transaction isolation level read serializable ...
RPC:Completed     exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1)...
```

Since I can see the first query IS actually executed under serializable (I can infer this from the locks its acquiring), the only rationale I can draw is that Audit Login simply states the ISO level of the SPID at the point of logging on, and *not* what it's changing it to.

If that's the case, then where's the event which triggers the ISO change? I have turned on ALL events and can't see anything...

Answer (score 1):

Changing the transaction isolation level is not an `RPC:Completed` event.

Double check if you are monitoring the `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted` events.

Comment: Already present in my traces. They do not show the isolation level for TransactionScopes.